# Python + opencv :ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to write a code that correct the V channel of my images by taking my first images as reference. But I am getting this error while trying to pass my correction value to all the pixel to the images.

I am not sure how to do it. How should I rewrite my code for that part? I tried and error a lot of times but still didnt managed to resolve the issue.

```
>>> 
 RESTART: C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/avergae.py 
[0.0, 103.81328149045861, 102.25728890139274, 100.11808781708474, 102.70660218168091, 104.8367051139934, 99.823930500250071, 104.96426229104148, 101.85104381075587, 102.09709583116921, 99.400945032365726, 92.15991298604699, 101.19626441549323, 103.19529341359842, 101.34438951969196, 102.6448956449741, 94.161672541871852, 91.460941106879034, 101.18572887210487, 101.6783903260298, 90.000500755040008]
103.81328149
[0.0, 0.0, 1.5559925890658661, 3.6951936733738648, 1.1066793087777, -1.0234236235347964, 3.9893509902085356, -1.1509808005828717, 1.9622376797027385, 1.716185659289394, 4.4123364580928808, 11.653368504411617, 2.6170170749653749, 0.6179880768601862, 2.4688919707666486, 1.168385845484508, 9.6516089485867553, 12.352340383579573, 2.6275526183537323, 2.134891164428808]
[[ 38  38  38 ...,  37  37  36]
 [ 38  37  38 ...,  38  38  38]
 [ 39  39  39 ...,  38  38  38]
 ..., 
 [141 141 142 ..., 160 161 161]
 [142 142 144 ..., 164 160 159]
 [142 142 143 ..., 168 162 159]]
3648
5472
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lian Ming/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/avergae.py", line 49, in <module>
    v[i,j] = v+int(deltaList[z])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

>>>
```

Code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

path = 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\experiment\\aligned\\'
path1 = 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\Desktop\\experiment\\aligned\\New folder\\'

img1 = cv2.imread(path + 'aligned_IMG_1770.png')
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h_reference, s_reference, v_reference = cv2.split(img1)
Average_V_Reference = np.average(v_reference)  #get the average of V for my first images as a reference value to compare to the rest of images

def ValueMean(im_file):  #Create a function that do the average on the V channel for all the images
    im = cv2.imread(im_file)
    im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h,s,v = cv2.split(im)
    a = np.average(v)
    return a             

myList = [0.0]
deltaList = [0.0] #store it in deltalist
num_images = 20

for i in range(1770, 1790):
    image_name = path + 'aligned_IMG_' + str(i) + '.png'
    myList.append(ValueMean(image_name)) #store all the images average into a list

print(myList)
print(Average_V_Reference)

for z in range(1, num_images):
    deltaList.append(z)
    deltaList[z] = Average_V_Reference - myList[z] #Data for all the difference in average value compared to reference images
print(deltaList)

z=1
for k in range(1770,1790):  #create a loop to recreate images based on the data i got
    a = 'aligned_IMG_' + str(k)
    image_name = path + a + '.png'
    img_file = cv2.imread(image_name)
    img_file = cv2.cvtColor(img_file, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h,s,v = cv2.split(img_file)
    print(v)
    print(img_file[:,:,2].shape[0])
    print(img_file[:,:,2].shape[1])
    for i in range(img_file[:,:,2].shape[0]): #passing correction value to each pixel on the V channel
        for j in range (img_file[:,:,2].shape[1]):
            v[i,j] = v+int(deltaList[z])
    z += 1
    img_file = cv2.merge((h,s,v))  #Merge back the HSV channel
    img_file = cv2.cvtColor(img_file, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR) #convert back to BGR and save
    new_image_name = path1 + 'BrightnessHSV_%d'%i + '.png'
    cv2.imwrite('new_image_name', new_image_name)
```

Comment: `v[i,j] = v+int(deltaList[z])`... on the left hand side, you have `v[i,j]`-- a single element of the array. On the right hand side, you have `v`, an entire array. It would be a good guess that assigning a whole image to a single pixel doesn't make much sense. The question is, why those loops are there in the first place, when a simple `v += int(deltaList[z])` can achieve the same thing in less code and much more quickly.

Comment: Do you mean `v[i,j] = v[i, j] +int(deltaList[z])`

Comment: @DanMašek thank you for your valuable input and suggestion...appreciate that. Do you know what I should add in to prevent overflow or underflow?

Comment: @SacreD No problem. I suggest spending some time reading through the numpy documentation, to get familiar with some of the basic functionality it provides. You don't need to memorize it, but it's good to have some idea about what's possible and where to look. The functions tend to be well optimized and avoid the overhead inherent in iterating pixel by pixel in Python. | How do you intend to handle the possible overflow or underflow? Let's talk at a single pixel level for now, and then we can try to translate it into some vectorized operation.

Comment: @SacreD This is unrelated, but I see you call `cv2.imread`, and then directly use the result. Keep in mind that when this function fails to read the image, it doesn't raise and exception, but instead it returns `None`. It would thus be prudent to verify that this didn't happen, before you pass this into other functions (some may not like that). Something like `if img1 is None:` which prints a meaningful error message and then terminates the application.

Comment: @DanMašek I wanted the array V channel stay within range (0-255). I tried    if np.any(v[i,j]) >255:
                v[i,j] = 255
                print(v[i,j])
            elif np.any(v[i,j]) <0:
                v[i,j] = 0
            else:
                v[i,j] = v[i,j]            But still getting                                                                        different brightness for each images using this method. sighh not sure if this method is doable anymore.

Comment: Well, you could convert the array to say int32 datatype for the correction, apply the offset and then use [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html).

Comment: @DanMašek. I realised my some of white pixel of images turn back and still getting uneven brightness overall for the images. Here's what i did. before applying offset. I change the v channel to np.float32, apply the offset value which i got. After that i add one line v[i,j] = np.clip(v[i,j], 0,255) to clip it and using v.astype(np.uint8) to change it back before merging the hsv channel and create new images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the following line would solve it

```
v[i,j] = v[i,j] +int(deltaList[z])
```

Comment: True. It's still a sub-optimal solution. Since it's adding the same value to all the elements in the matrix, the operation can be performed [in one step](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations) and a much more efficient manner.